# Java definition of infinity

Tags: java, 64-bit, infinity

I try to run this code in java

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(2,1024));
System.out.println(Math.pow(2,1023));
```

the results:

> Infinity
>
> 8.98846567431158E307

I'm wondering - why 2^1024 is infinity? and 2^1023 isn't? I guess that there is a connection to the fact that 1024 is 2^10, but I don't really get it. Also, will the answer change if I will try to run it in a machine with 124 bit instead of 64 bit?

little confused, will appreciate any help :)

Comment: Because `Double.MAX_VALUE` is less than 2^1024 but more than 2^1023

Comment: @harold but again, there is a reason that Double.MAX_VALUE defined to be between 2^1023 and 2^1024? actually, we can say that the max_value is close to 2^1024. if you try to do 2^1023 * *1.9999999999999998 in java you will get 1.7976931348623157E308 and it is equal to double MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Yes there is an real reason (other than arbitrary choice) for both, the maximum exponent is 1023 but you can go *almost* to 1024 by setting all bits of the significand.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "124-bit machine" in Java. The size of Java's primitive types is defined in the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

that is because the calculation goes outside of the double precision. You will see the same result in a "124"  bit machine.